# How to prove that multivariable function has a minima?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider for example the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
$$f\left(x,y,z\right)\:=\:z^2+3x^2+y^2-2xy+14$$
I need to prove the $f$ has a minima and to calculate it.

So far i went to the definitions:

> If $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\lim _{v\to \infty }\left(f\left(v\right)\right)\:=\infty \:$ then $f$ has a minima

Now, i searched for the meaning of $\lim _{v\to \infty }\left(f\left(v\right)\right)\:=\infty \:$ and it's as follows:

> $\lim _{v\to \infty }\left(f\left(v\right)\right)\:=\infty \:$ if 
>   $\forall M>0$ $\exists T>0$ $\forall v\in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $\|v\|>T$ then $f\left(v\right)>M$

So my question actually is, How to show that $$\lim _{v\to \infty }\left(f\left(v\right)\right)\:=\infty \:$$
Can someone guide me in steps? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You'll find that most people don't know "how to sh", so please write your question in full.

Comment: Hint: Write it as a sum of squares plus a constant. Then if the squares are simultaneously zero you have a minimum.

Comment: @MarkBennet so i wrote it and i got $x^2+\left(y-z\right)^2+2\:z^2+14$ but how to show the squares are simultaneously zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that: $$ f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (x - y)^2 + x^2 + 14 \ge  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 14  \tag{1} $$

Now if you want to prove that $\lim _{v\to \infty }\left(f\left(v\right)\right)\:=\infty \:$ using the definition,

**Proof:** Let $ M \gt 0 $ be arbitrary. Choose $T = \max \{M, 1\} $ which will be a positive quantity. Now, Suppose $ || (x, y, z) || \gt T $ where $v = (x, y, z)$. Then naturally,$$f(v) \ge  x^2 + y^2 + z^2  = || (x, y, z) || ^2 \ge || (x, y, z) ||  \ge T \ge  M $$

$\mathscr {Q.E.D.}$

Now as per $(1)$ $f(v) \ge x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 14$ and $ f(0,0,0) = 14 $ which gives you the point at which the minima occurs.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you got "Choose $T=max{M,1}$"

Comment: Don't know "how"? I'll tell you "why"? Simply, because it works. All you need to notice is the $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2  $ term.